# XMLHTTP Connection

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

So I have this code :

```
function checkStatus()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

if (xmlhttp.responseText == "1") {
document.getElementById("maincontent").innerHTML = '<br/><br/><center>Please refresh the page to continue.</b></center>';
}
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","file.php?id=1",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and I'm wondering about the last 2 lines (xmlhttp.open and xmlhttp.send) , what is the function of these ? also when i go to file file.php?id=1 using the browser it only displays "0" whereas the the general function of the code is to redirect me to a website after i do a specific action and i believe the data is stored on file.php?id=1 but how can i see it from browser ?
Note: I'm not HTML/PHP programmer but i recognize the basics

Comment: You should add your PHP code if you want answer for your second question related to PHP

Comment: Are you really still supporting IE5 and IE6? (if so, you're mad; if not, you can simplify your code by dropping the ActiveX bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines before `xmlhttp.open()` just create the `XMLHttpRequest` object that will handle the AJAX connection. Calling `xmlhttp.open()` is necessary to actually open the connection and `xmlhttp.send()` to send the request. Only after the request is sent, a response can be received and handled by the `onreadystatechange` handler.

This code looks rather obsolete, however. I would recommend not using `XMLHttpRequest` directly but rather use a library for it - see [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), for example.

Comment: Thanks for help . Okey , I have a question , how can i display the response ? like using echo function to display it ?

Comment: for debugging purposes, just use `window.alert()`. For a real application you can use something like `<div id="abc"></div>` and JavaScript `document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML="mytext"`. But you'd better post a new question for that to get more complete answers.

Comment: as I've stated above I'm not HTML/PHP programmer , so can you please help me a bit ? How can I know the where is the response defined ? so I put it window.alert(response) for example ...